# Javascript <br> in TypeWriter Effect

Tags: javascript

I try to create a typeWriter effect using Javascript. It done perfectly, but it cannot type '<' character. I don't know how to fix it

**My code is:**

```js
let other = document.getElementById('other');
let txt = "Hello World <br> this typing effect.";
let i = 0;
function typeWriter() {
    if (i < txt.length) {
      other.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i); i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, 10);
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<h1 id='other'></h1>
```

**I hope the result like:**

```
Hello World
this typing effect.
```

**Actual result I get:**

```
Hello World <br> this typing effect.
```

Please give me some clue. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use escape character and css

Answer (score 3):

You just need to know two things,

1. How `white-space` are handled in html?

   By nature it will collapse all the extra spaces and line into linear format.

   You can break it using `white-space` css property. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)
2. Escape characters (escape sequence)

   A character escape represents a character that may not be able to be conveniently represented in its literal form.

   Here `\n` denotes a new line. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Character_escape)

```js
let other = document.getElementById('other');
let txt = `Hello World \nthis typing effect.`;
let i = 0;
function typeWriter() {
    if (i < txt.length) {
      other.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i); i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, 10);
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
}

typeWriter();
```

```css
#other{
  white-space: pre-line; /* magic is here */
}
```

```html
<h1 id='other'></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Great question and it had me fooled at first.

When `typewriter` reaches the point where it sets `outer.innerHTML` to

```
Hello World <
```

the HTML parser doesn't find a well formed tag at the end, so it replaces '<' with `&lt;` to create valid HTML source to render a less-than sign.

When you add additional characters afterward, the `&lt;` escape is already part of `outer.innerHTML`, so when you add the `>` character, it too isn't part of a tag and gets converted to a `&gt;` escape.

Hence the final result you see on screen is a rendering of

```
 Hello World &lt;br&gt; this typing effect.
```

---

One solution would be to split the input string into an array of lines using `<br>` as the separator, then type each line individually with the typewriter effect, in conjunction with inserting `<br>` in the HTML at the end of each line.

A more authentic effect for your consideration might be to add individual characters to the `textContent` property of `#outer` in a pair of `<pre><code id="outer"></code></pre>` nested elements. You would need to replace all `<br>` *character sequences* with `\n` in `txt` for it to produce a line feed in the `<pre>` element box.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can handle each instance of `<br>` by:

1. applying the typewriter until encountering tag: `<sometag>`,
2. directly adding `<sometag>` to `other.innerHTML`,
3. continue applying your effect to the rest of the string.

```js
let other = document.getElementById('other');
let txt = "Hello World <br> this typing effect.<br>break again?!";
let i = 0;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    if (txt.substring(i, i + 4) === '<br>') {
      other.innerHTML += '<br>';
      i += 4;
    } else {
      other.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
      i++;
    }
    setTimeout(typeWriter, 10);
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<h1 id='other'></h1>
```

You can also extend this to handle any HTML tag by checking for the pattern of `<foo>...</foo>` if you want to try tags including anchor and list elements

Comment: You could also do that using `\n` and `white-space` and `<br>` is literally old trend.

Comment: True, good call @YuvarajM